# Error in using global variables in spark project

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

In a PySpark project containing several .py files, there is a file called `settings.py` to declare all the global variables.

```
# settings.py

def prepareMyList():
    return ['35','19','10','25']

def setGlobal():
    global ageList
    ageList = prepareMyList()
```

Now, another file `utils.py` contain the filtering method.

```
# utils.py

import settings

def returnIfTrue(row):
    if row[1] in settings.ageList:
        return row
```

`Filtering.py` performs the filtering on the RDD utilizing the method in `utils.py` file.

```
# filtering.py

import utils

def doFiltering(fileRDD):
    filteredRDD = fileRDD.filter(utils.returnIfTrue)
    return filteredRDD
```

The `main.py` is the following.

```
# main.py

from pyspark import SparkContext
import settings
import filtering

sc = SparkContext()
settings.setGlobal()
rawRDD = sc.textFile("/path/to/Data/")
splittedRDD = rawRDD.map(lambda l:l.split(","))
filteredRDD = filtering.doFiltering(splittedRDD)
for row in filteredRDD.collect():
    print row
```

When the project is run, it is throwing an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ageList'`.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
  process()
File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
  serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
  vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "utils.py", line 6, in returnIfTrue
  if row[1] in settings.ageList:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ageList'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: But have you declared ageList?
`
ageList = None
def setGlobal():
    global ageList
    ageList = prepareMyList()
`

Answer (score 0):

But have actually declared ageList? Try this.

```
ageList = None
def setGlobal():
    global ageList
    ageList = prepareMyList()
```

Comment: Didn't work. Showing `TypeError`. `NoneType not iterable`.

Comment: Of course, default value is `None`. Replace it with `[]` if you want to have an empty list instead.